# Expansion of Gamma function at half integers, around an integer

Tags: taylor-expansion, gamma-function

From the Taylor series expansion of the Gamma function, I know that:

$$ \Gamma\!\left(z + \frac12\right) = \Gamma(z) + \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma^{(k)}(z)}{k!}\left(\frac12\right)^k,
$$
where $\Gamma^{(k)}(z) = \frac{d^k}{dz^k}\Gamma(z)$, and for any $z$. My question is: is there an (perhaps, analytical) expression for these derivatives at $z\in\mathbb N$, a positive integer.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Logarithmic derivatives of $\Gamma$ are called [polygamma functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function?useskin=vector)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obtain a recurrence relation for those values. First note that, for $k\ge 1$,
$$
\frac{{{\rm d}^k \Gamma (z)}}{{{\rm d}z^k }} = \frac{{{\rm d}^{k - 1} }}{{{\rm d}z^{k - 1} }}(\psi^{(0)} (z)\Gamma (z)) = \sum\limits_{j = 0}^{k - 1} {\binom{k-1}{j}\psi ^{(j)} (z)\frac{{{\rm d}^{k - j - 1} \Gamma (z)}}{{{\rm d}z^{k - j - 1} }}} ,
$$
where $\psi^{(j)}$ is a [polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function). Assume that $z = n \ge 1$
is an integer. Then
$$
\psi ^{(0)} (n) =  - \gamma  + \sum\limits_{r = 1}^{n - 1} {\frac{1}{r}}, 
$$
with $\gamma$ being the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant), and
$$
\psi ^{(j)} (n) = ( - 1)^{j + 1} j!\sum\limits_{r = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{(r + n)^{j + 1} }}}  = ( - 1)^{j + 1} j!\bigg( {\zeta (j + 1) - \sum\limits_{r = 1}^{n - 1} {\frac{1}{{r^{j + 1} }}} } \bigg)
$$
for $j\ge 1$, with $\zeta$ being the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

Of course, the formula
$$
\Gamma\! \left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right) = \frac{{(2n)!}}{{4^n n!}}\sqrt \pi  
$$
provides a much more efficient way to compute the gamma function for half-integer values.

Comment: Thanks @Gary Yes, indeed, but I want to write it in terms of Gamma at integer values!