# Why do the constants $\gamma$, $\zeta(2)$ and $\zeta(3)$ appear in the values of $\Gamma''(1)$ and $\Gamma'''(1)$?

Tags: calculus, gamma-function, riemann-zeta

I have been interested in the gamma function and its derivatives recently and was surprised to see these constants appear in the values of the derivatives of the gamma function:
$$\Gamma'(1) = -\gamma$$
$$\Gamma''(1) = \gamma^2 + \zeta(2)$$
$$\Gamma'''(1) = -2\zeta(3)-\gamma^3-\frac{\gamma\pi^2}{2}$$

I have read that $$-\int_0^\infty e^{-t}\ln(t)dt$$ is a definition of $\gamma$, which also happens to be $-\Gamma'(1)$, so this isn't very surprising to see showing up in higher derivatives of $\Gamma(z)$. I am more curious about where the zeta values are coming from. I should clarify that I am currently taking calculus 2 and the basic integration techniques I know don't seem to get me anywhere in solving these by hand, so I got these closed form values from Wolfram Alpha. Maybe there is some more advanced technique which would easily explain where the zetas are coming from?

Comment: the zeta function gives the Taylor coefficients of the log gamma function, so it should not be surprising to see them among the values of the derivatives

Comment: Does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4875256

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of applying repeatedly the Leibniz integral rule for differentiation under the integral sign (the case with constant limits of integration) which you might do in Calculus II:
$$\begin{aligned}
\Gamma'(1)=\left[\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz}\displaystyle\int_0^\infty x^{z-1}e^{-x}\mathrm dx\right|_{z=1}&=\left[\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\partial e^{(z-1)\ln x}}{\partial z}e^{-x}\mathrm dx\right|_{z=1}\\
&=\left[\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \ln xe^{(z-1)\ln x}e^{-x}\mathrm dx\right|_{z=1}\\
&=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \ln x\ e^{-x}\mathrm dx=-\gamma
\end{aligned}
$$
$$\begin{aligned}
\Gamma''(1)=\left[\dfrac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dz^2}\displaystyle\int_0^\infty x^{z-1}e^{-x}\mathrm dx\right|_{z=1}&=\left[\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz}\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\partial e^{(z-1)\ln x}}{\partial z}e^{-x}\mathrm dx\right|_{z=1}\\
&=\left[\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz}\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \ln xe^{(z-1)\ln x}e^{-x}\mathrm dx\right|_{z=1}\\
&=...\\
&=\left[\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \ln^2 xe^{(z-1)\ln x}e^{-x}\mathrm dx\right|_{z=1}\\
&=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \ln^2 x\ e^{-x}\mathrm dx=\gamma^2+\zeta(2)
\end{aligned}
$$
Idem for the third derivative.

In general,
$$\Gamma^{(n)}(1)=\left[\dfrac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dz^n}\displaystyle\int_0^\infty x^{z-1}e^{-x}\mathrm dx\right|_{z=1}=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \ln^n x\ e^{-x}\mathrm dx$$

---

If you wanted the explicit calculations for each integral there might be some MSE post covering this or some online paper talking about these types of integrals.